# Get type (php, python, dotnet)of applications running on IIS using powershell script

Tags: powershell, iis, powershell-remoting

I want to get type of application running on IIS. I have python, php, java application running on IIS. Using Powershell command how can I recognize the type of application running behind IIS.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\Sites
```

Gives me all website hosted on IIS with physical path but I need information about is it a python site or php site? 
Interpreter for pyhton or php is enabled but how site and interpreter works together I don't understant.

Solved with fetching interpreter information from web.config file.
Every interpreter is listed in web.config file.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: As per my research some CGI settings needs to be enable and configure handler mapping with correct executable path. see link https://medium.com/@bilalbayasut/deploying-python-web-app-flask-in-windows-server-iis-using-fastcgi-6c1873ae0ad8

Comment: but not able to find the connection between hosted sites and CGI interpreter.

Comment: Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\Sites this gives me all sites information with physical path, name etc. But I need interpreter used for specific hosted application example if site is python then i need something to recognize it as python site.